# Using the same title

Tags: routes, routing, category

I have an article called Main Article and I am rolling out the chapters each week (8x). So, each chapter will have the MAIN Article Title AND Chapter Title.
eg: Stories from the top of the World; The Journey of the arborists

Stories from the top of the World; The way to the top
etc, etc...

I could create the MAIN Article as a single entry (with an excerpt) but this is not the brief from the client and use a relationship field to add the chapters to the Main Article Title.

I could add the Main Article title as a category and select this at each chapter entry, but how do I create the URL format to do this? This might also be tough to explain as a workflow for the client....

```
articles/{category}/{slug}
```

What else are the options?

Answer (score 2):

You can set the URL format to be anything you want really, just setup your templates and then setup some routes; then it's all going to work automatic for your client and they never have to worry about it.

Comment: Thanks Christopher, this is my first site in Craft, so I need to wrap my head around the routing. Nevertheless it's awkward to add a title as a Category - I wonder if there is another way?

Comment: If it's a pre-set number of entries you could use a Structure rather than a Channel, then it'd all flow automatically and make logical sense to everybody without the need for any fancy logic.

Comment: yes, that would make sense, but there os no way of knowing how many chapters future articles will have..

Comment: The point though is that you want a set of entries that HAVE a relation to each other and hierarchy. That is Exactly what the Structure section type is meant for. So your options as I see it are, do it however you think makes sense to you and setup routes to handle the URLs, OR use a Structure and you don't really have to do anything that isn't basic and standard.